# Maximum Trigger Depth/Recursive Loop

Tags: apex, trigger

So a little background. This trigger works on insert but no on update(of course). I've created a helper class to help with the maximum trigger depth, but I'm having some issues with the first part of the trigger.

I believe the issue is coming from the first couple of lines, where the id is put into a list by the for loop, and the query below goes to it and retrieves that ID. Once it fires again, it goes back to retrieve that same ID over and over again.

I've put logic around those couple of lines but I either get the maximum trigger depth or the SOQL 101 error. Anybody got any ideas about how to solve it? I'm sure that its something simple that I'm missing.

Oh btw I plan to move this over to an Apex helper class as soon as i get it working just fyi.

```
trigger LeadReassignmentTrigger on Lead (after insert, after update) //after update
{
public Lead LeadRecordName {get;set;}
public Contact contactInsert {get;set;}
public QueueSobject Queue {get;set;}
list<Id> LeadIdList = new list<Id>();
public Account AccountRecordsName {get;set;}
public Lead LeadInsert {get;set;}
public integer Counter {get;set;}


for(Lead leads : trigger.new)
{
  LeadIdList.add(leads.id);

}

//I think this is where the issue is happening. It this query is grabbing the id from the leadidlist every time the trigger fires, which happens after every update. I checked the logs and this query is firing over and over again.
try{
            LeadInsert = [SELECT id, 
                          email, 
                          Ownerid 
                          FROM Lead 
                          where id in : LeadIdList limit 1];
}
Catch(Exception e)

{}
 try{
    //public Contact contactInsert = [SELECT email, Ownerid FROM Contact   where email =: LeadInsert.email limit 1];
 contactInsert =        [SELECT email, 
                         Ownerid 
                         FROM Contact 
                         where email =: LeadInsert.email limit 1];

}
catch(Exception e){

}
//3.3

//List<Contact> ContactRecords = [SELECT email, Ownerid FROM Contact where id in : LeadIdList];
List<Lead> LeadRecords = [SELECT 
                          email, 
                          Lead.Lead_Lifecycle__c, 
                          id, 
                          ownerid 
                          FROM Lead 
                          where Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()
                          limit 1];
    for (Lead LD: LeadRecords){
        //if(Lead_Trigger_Helper.runonce()){
        if(LD.Lead_Lifecycle__c == 'AQL' && LD.email == contactInsert.email){
            if(LD.email != null){
 //List<Contact> ContactRecords = [SELECT email FROM Contact];
 //List<Lead> LeadRecords = [SELECT email FROM Lead where email =:ContactRecords.email];
         LD.OwnerId = contactInsert.ownerid;

            }

             }

       // } 

  }
  upsert LeadRecords;


 //3.3, number 2 FSR 

List<Lead> LeadRecordsName = [SELECT email,
                              Lead.Lead_Lifecycle__c, 
                              id, ownerid, 
                              Company, 
                              name 
                              FROM Lead 
                              where Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()];

            Queue =           [SELECT Id,
                              queue.Name, 
                              QueueId 
                              FROM QueueSobject 
                              WHERE queue.Name = :'VP Queue'
                              limit 1];

             LeadRecordName = [SELECT email, 
                              Lead.Lead_Lifecycle__c, 
                              id, 
                              ownerid, 
                              Company, 
                              name 
                              FROM Lead 
                              where Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()
                              limit 1];

 try{
 AccountRecordsName = 
                              [SELECT id, 
                              Name, 
                              ownerid 
                              FROM Account 
                              where Name =: LeadRecordName.Company
                              limit 1];
 }
        Catch (Exception e)
        {}
try{
             counter = 
                             [SELECT 
                              Count() 
                              FROM Accountteammember 
                              where accountid=:AccountRecordsName.id 
                              ];
}
catch (Exception e){}

  for (Lead LD2: LeadRecordsName){

  //List<Lead> LeadRecordsName = [SELECT email, Lead.Lead_Lifecycle__c, id, ownerid, Company, name FROM Lead where Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
    if(LD2.Company != null && counter != null)
    {
    if(LD2.Company == AccountRecordsName.Name && counter == 1) //&&
    {
        try{
          Accountteammember AccountTeamMemberInfo = [SELECT 
                                           accountid, 
                                           userid
                                           from Accountteammember 
                                           where  accountid=:AccountRecordsName.id
                                           limit 1];


    LD2.ownerid = AccountTeamMemberInfo.userid;
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }
    if(LD2.Company == AccountRecordsName.Name && counter > 1) //&&
    {
        //Finish Query. Test?

     LD2.ownerid = queue.QueueId;   
    }
    //LD2.ownerid = Queue.id; 

    //put an else statement in here that can assign it to a que
  //}
    }



 }
 upsert LeadRecordsName;

//3.4, ISR
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an improper use of the if(Lead_Trigger_Helper.runonce()). Once I fixed that and wrapped it correctly, it works without and complications.

Answer (score 1):

`upsert LeadRecordsName;` is in your for loop, so your inserting records, and your trigger will kick off again since it may be a update or a insert.. Fix your indents and formatting and you would of caught that.

Oops, didn't see this one also `update LeadRecords;`  It's also in a for loop.  But to add some more clarity of what's happening.

Your Trigger fires 
Updates one record(because it's in a for loop)
Trigger Fires again
Updates one record
And on, and on.

Comment: Didn't solve it.

Comment: Can you post your changes?

Comment: I edited the original to reflect the changes.

Comment: yeah the last version I posted has all the update/upsert calls outside the for loops. That was definitely an issue but im not sure if that was the cause because the issue is still persisting. I think it's because of the first couple lines where the

 for(Lead leads : trigger.new)
{
  LeadIdList.add(leads.id);

}

Comment: Well to be honest, and blunt you have 9 queries in there, so I'm assuming you do this a lot with your code.  SOQL Limit Errors is an aggregate from everything ran in that context, so this may not be the culprit, it just breaks on that one.  I think you should brush up on some best practices https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

Comment: @Christian What did you do to fix it?

Comment: Turns out it was an improper use of the if(Lead_Trigger_Helper.runonce()). Once I fixed that and wrapped it correctly, it works without and complications.